# PHP Selecting from external database is extremely slow

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am running a simple query in PHP to an external MySQL Database:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) as n FROM `call_history` where extension_number = '0536*500' and flow = 'in' and DATE(initiated) =\"{$initiated}\"";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$pbx01_conn);
$rs = mysql_fetch_row($rs);
echo $rs['n'];
```

which seems to take forever to run, there is about **4000000+** rows in this table.

I do not have full write access to the database, only read access. Is there anything I can do to speed up the query?

Comment: If there exist any index on `initiated` it will not be used because using a date function on it

Comment: How long does this take to run the query via command line / phpmyadmin ?  and are you sure the query is exactly right, ie, echo $sql, before you run it.  Otherwise you need better where conditions or possibly indexing on your mysql DB... could be a number of issues...

Comment: there is no phpmyadmin installed on the server, it takes around 1 minute to return any results but this page is meant to be a dashboard with how many phone calls have been into the company for the current day so it cannot be slow

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can use an index on your last filtering criteria the way you currently have it structured.

By comparing to `DATE(initiated)` to your input value, you disallow use of an index on `initiated` (which I assume is a timestamp or datetime field) and trigger a full table scan, since the value for comparison has to be calculated.

Try something like this for your last condition:

```
AND initiated BETWEEN '? 00:00:00' AND '? 23:59:59'
```

Where `?` is your variable in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

One you have that fixed, you just need to make sure you have indexes on `extension_number,`flow`, and of course`initiated`.  Without these indexes, you have no way to fully optimize your query.  So if you don't have write access on that table and those indexes are missing, you should get with whoever does have that write access to see if the indexes can be added (note adding the indexes would impact insert performance on the table).